# Why canvas drawing is asynchronous, but API is synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, canvas, browser

I am writing a vizualization of neural network, and I would like to redraw it on each training iteration, so I have next button with onclick callback:

```
startButton.onclick = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < trainData.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      network.trainSample(trainData[i])
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
      drawNN(network)
    }, 0)
  }
}
```

The problem is, if I take off `setTimeout`, it will execute all the training, and redraw everything in the end.

As far as I know, there is an event loop and what `setTimeout` trick does, it creates a Job in a event queue that will be executed **not exactly now, but as soon as possible**.

Okay, but if canvas drawing is asynchronous and drawing get's postponed till the end, why it's api is synchronous?

Minimal example:

```js
const canv = document.getElementById('myCanv')
const ctx = canv.getContext('2d')

ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'

for (let x = 0; x <= 100; x++) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
  ctx.lineTo(x, 100)
  ctx.stroke()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas width="100" height="100" id="myCanv"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How is your premise linked to your question? Here your setTimeout is absolutely unnecessary since all your script will be run synchronously, even if in the next event loop

Comment: @Kaiido, unfortunately it doesn't. I want this to redraw on each iteration, but if I don't do `setTimeout`, context2d `clearRect` function is going to be put on processing queue but won't be run synchronously. Putting the whole thing into the settimeout calls this block together.

Comment: That makes no sense. Write an [mcve] please.

Comment: @Kaiido updated the post. As you see I was wondering for some kind of animation - but only last iteration is being drawed, because browser executes scripts, and draws only after.

Comment: I don't see how this is an example of what you described. There is no setTimeout there, and if there was, the result would be exactly the same.

Comment: @Kaiido the difference is, if I've put settime on it and if it needed some time to compute, it would make a delay before painting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage is incorrect and even if canvas drawing was synchronous you most likely would see only the last frame anyway with some way too fast weird animation in between. What you need is instead of standard loop use some sort of animation loop. For example:

```js
let i = 0;
function animationLoop() {
  if (i < trainData.length) {
     network.trainSample(trainData[i]);
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
     drawNN(network);
     i++;
     requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
  }
}
requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
```

Here I am using `requestAnimationFrame` which would result in around 60 frames per second. My guess for your case this might still be too fast. You can limit frames per second using additional `setTimeout` inside `animateLoop` function.